# SimpleCV not responding after clicking the picture

Tags: python, simplecv

I'm trying out SimpleCV and I'm noticing every time I click title bar, simplecv stops working to the pint that it crashes. Before crashing it says "pythonw.exe Stopped working." That happens if I edit my script and run it from the python idle. If I simply double click it, the image is displayed for 20secs and then just closes.

This is what I tried. Really simple.

```
from SimpleCV import Image

img = Image("carro.jpg")

img = img.scale(300,300)

img.show()
```

Just wondering if this could causes any kind of trouble while doing some image processing like subtracting colors and stuff like that.

Comment: What operating system are you using (Windows)? What you are doing should be perfectly fine. Changing the image after showing it is perfectly legal.

Comment: Maybe it's my pc lol It's getting a bit old.

Comment: You might try posting the crash you observed on the simplecv question and answer site: http://help.simplecv.org/questions/ (thats not normal). I found that changing the backend to use QT helped solve a lot of issues on my Mac (not sure about windows). See http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html "What is a backend section." to see how to do this.  Try doing img.live() also.

Comment: ran it on the raspberry pi and did the same thing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and after searching found this: From http://help.simplecv.org/question/1118/why-imageshow-freezes/ it looks like it is caused by pyGame requiring a while loop to keep pumping events to the window.

The solution, as indicated at that post, and worked for me, was to use the `quit()` method on the window handle returned by `show`.

````

```
img = Image("carro.jpg")

img = img.scale(300,300)

win = img.show()

#wait for user input before closing
raw_input()

win.quit()
```

````